# value not getting updated in the view

Tags: angularjs

I have a ui-select, after the user presses the save button, ui select should get reset to the initial value.

ui-select -

```
    <ui-select multiple ng-model="selectedGroup" ng-change="selectGroups(selectedGroup)" style="width:250px;">
        <ui-select-match placeholder="Select groups...">{{$item}}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices repeat="group in groups| filter:$select.search">
                            {{group}}
        </ui-select-choices>
    </ui-select>
```

in the controller :

```
    $scope.save = function(){
           // some logic
           $scope.selectedGroup = ["group1"];
       }
```

Value of the ui select is not getting updated. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `ng-model` in `<ui-select>` must have a dot(.) expression like this

```
<ui-select multiple ng-model="model.selectedGroup" ng-change="selectGroups(model.selectedGroup)" style="width:250px;">
```

In your controller code, you can set the initial value of the property specified in the ng-model like this

```
$scope.model = {
  selectedGroup: ["group1"] 
};
```